# How to set the selected menu highlighted after page refresh

Tags: html, jquery

I have got a task to do horizontal menu.Here I have a problem with the selection of menu.This is my code.But after page refresh the selected menu will disappear.How can i solve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .menu{width: 300px; height: 25; font-size: 18px;}
  .menu li{list-style: none; float: left; margin-right: 4px; padding: 5px;}
  .menu li:hover, .menu li.active {
        background-color: #f90;
    }
</style>

<ul class="menu">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li class="active">Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
<li>Item 6</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

var make_button_active = function()
{
    var siblings =($(this).siblings());

    siblings.each(function (index)
    {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  )


    $(this).addClass('active');
}

$(document).ready(
  function()
  {
    $(".menu li").click(make_button_active);
  }  
)

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the page refresh, Entire page is redrwan. you need to use cookies or session to store them.  [LocalStorage.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
you can use HTML5 LocalStorage.

```
var yourObj= { 'key': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3 };

localStorage.setItem('yourObj', JSON.stringify(yourObj));

var getStoredObj= localStorage.getItem('yourObj');
```

Comment: Is there any other idea on this? I dn't have the permission to do this. Can I generate dynamic id from this..?

Comment: @Monica i updated answer. please read the loclastorage in MDN

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways that I can think of.

You haven't specified if you are using MVC or not so if you are then you could simply replace the updated section of the screen with a partial view and nothing more needs to happen.

If however you are returning the whole page and you have sessionState then you will need to set the value of a hidden field to the ID of the menu clicked.

Then when the page is rebuilt, you should still have the hidden field value in session state, get the value and enable that menu item.

If you are allowed to have cookies, then set one of them to the id of the menu and again once the page is built highlight that menu.

**EDIT**

```
        $(".menuSomeMenu").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                data: {
                    menuClicked: 'the menu clicked for the backend to use
                },
                url: "/Home/Ajax_MenuClickEvent",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".MyPartialViewContainer").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Then in your controller;

```
public ActionResult Ajax_MenuClickEvent(Guid StoreId)
{
    return PartialView("MyPartialView", modelToPassToPartialView);
}
```

Comment: Right, then return a partial view of what on the page has changed.  Let me know if you need an example

Comment: I need an example for that.Is there any possibility with jquery?

Comment: @griegs-I have the same problem.. please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739503/how-to-set-the-menu-as-selected-while-loading-using-jquery

Comment: @Agent1, you have an identical problem and you need to either store the menu item that you want to re-select or you need to use MVC like it is meant to and load only part of the page with the use of AJAX and Partial Views.